# The browser or gateway element with ID 'Safari60' cannot be found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.5, inappbrowser

We have  changed .net version  2.0 to 4.5 of my website. We are using “App_Browsers/safari.browser”  for  some safari issue on Mac and its working fine for 2.2 framework.
When we changed .net version then it given error “The browser or gateway element with ID 'Safari60' cannot be found.”  When we remove this file then it’s working fine  but we get safari issue. So we need this file on my website. Can anybody let me know how we can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Framework of Visual Studio you install,
you need to Update the browser definition file under App_Browser folder with the new browser definition you get under the following path:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\Browsers